# How to use Bootstrap's tooltip.js's randomized id as the selector?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap's [tooltip.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js), and I am trying to set up this functionality: When a tooltip is open, pressing the ESC key closes it. Here is my code, inserted after `Tooltip.prototype.fixTitle`, which begins at `line 345`:

```
  Tooltip.prototype.escapeTooltip = function () {
    // ESC key closes all tooltips

    $(this.$element).keydown(function (event) {
      if (event.which === 27) {
        $('.tooltip').tooltip('hide');
      }
    });
  }
```

Then I call `this.escapeTooltip()` within `if (this.hasContent() && this.enabled)` at `line 184`

So instead of using the class `.tooltip` as the selector for hiding the tooltip, is there anyway I can use `$tipId`, which is defined like `var tipId = this.getUID(this.type)` at `line 193`? `$tipId` uses a randomly generated ID for each tooltip that is created. I was thinking of something like this: `$(this.$tipId).tooltip('hide');` but unfortunately that doesn't work.

**NOTE**: I am detaching the keydown event like so:

```
  Tooltip.prototype.destroy = function () {
    var that = this
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.hide(function () {
      that.$element.off('.' + that.type).removeData('bs.' + that.type)

      // Detaching keydown handler
      that.$element.off("keydown")

      if (that.$tip) {
        that.$tip.detach()
      }
      that.$tip = null
      that.$arrow = null
      that.$viewport = null
    })
  }
```